# Controlling font size in math environment, fine tuning

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

In my document using `\documentclass[12pt]{report}`, I have tables containing an index and a inequality in each line. As it's a long list, it's a `supertabular` with columns `c|rcr`. Sample data of one line is `1 & x_{i,j} & \leq & 0 \\`.

Now, in this specific table, I prefer typewriter style.
Additionally, the length of these inequalities is too high to fit with normal text size, therefore, I also reduce the font size.
To have this in every math environment without repetition of commands I've declared a specific environment:

```
\newenvironment {specialMath} [0] {} {}
\AtBeginEnvironment{specialMath}
{
\everymath{\scriptstyle\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
\everydisplay{\scriptstyle\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
}
```

It works, in the sense that everything is displayed at the size of subscripts.
However, printed on A4, this is a bit too small.

In summary, `\textstyle` is too large, `\scriptstyle` too small, but I do not want to adjust *all* font sizes (that can be done with `\DeclareMathSizes{...` in the preamble, afaik).

How do I fine tune the font size locally, not globally, in a set of math environments?

A minimal compilable example (pdflatex), without the table:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                 % math environment
\usepackage{etoolbox}                                % environment customization
\usepackage{supertabular}                            % multi-page tables

\newenvironment {specialMath} [0] {} {}
\AtBeginEnvironment{specialMath}
{
\everymath{\scriptstyle\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
\everydisplay{\scriptstyle\mathtt{\xdef\tmp{\fam\the\fam\relax}\aftergroup\tmp}}
}

\begin{document}

$x_{i,j} \leq 0$ % normal style
\begin{specialMath}
\begin{supertabular}{r}
$x_{i,j} \leq 0$\\ % typewriter, slightly smaller
\end{supertabular}
\end{specialMath}
$x_{i,j} \leq 0$ % normal style again
\end{document}
```

Without the supertabular, somehow it's not typewriter font. It will be used in a tabular anyway, but you can ignore that fact.

Comment: May I ask why you are doing this? It sounds to me to be something that ends up having a rather inconsistent design.

Comment: Your example does not print typewriter style for me.  Anyway have you consider `\scalebox{0.9}{$x_{i,j} \leq 0$}` with `\usepackage{graphicx}`?

Comment: @daleif The data is too long to fit in one row, as I've written in my question. It has to be smaller for fitting into one row. The tables are all at the end, so it's not really inconsistent.

Comment: @AndrewSwann You're right, curiously it's not typewriter style, not sure why though. I will correct this if I find the error. But this shouldn't affect the question.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Updated, curiously it works with a supertabular wrapper, but that's how I use it anyway. I suspect supertabular includes the correct package, but whatever.

Comment: @stefan, but still to me its sound more like a rewrite is in order.

Comment: @daleif what do you mean by that?

Comment: That in most cases when people are tempted to reduce font sizes to make things fit, then it is often because they haven't explored other options, including a rewrite or asked them selfs: is this a good way to present this. It depends on the situation of course.

Comment: @daleif Well the data is fixed, no rewrite possible. It shouldn't be too hard to change the font size, should it?

Comment: Why not show us some data that is a bit closer to realy life. I see a lot of people just choosing `change the font size, now it fits` instead of taking a closer look at what they are doing.

Comment: @daleif: Well it's all something like this: `3x_{i,j} +x_{i,k} +3x_{i,l} +x_{j,k} +2x_{k,i} +x_{k,j} +2x_{k,l} +x_{l,i} +2x_{l,j} -2w_{i,j} +2w_{i,k} -w_{i,l} -2w_{j,k} +w_{j,l} -w_{k,l}  \leq  3`. Not sure about how this would help you. Please don't suggest wrapping the inequality, I've tried that, it's ugly. Rotating the table by 90 degrees is also out of question. I want to change the font size, not anything else. I think it would be polite to simply accept that wish. If you don't know the answer or don't want to answer, that's fine, of course.

Comment: Why is there a `supertabular` in the middle`? And why one just with the column a with then it is automatically broken into lines.

Comment: @daleif, As i previously explained in the comments (and now also the question), without the supertabular, the typewriter font is not applied.

Comment: I still do not understand why you would present such long lines for the reader, you will end up with such a small font size that they would need a magnifying glass.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about `\scriptstyle`; here's what I'd do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\newenvironment{specialMath}
  {\footnotesize\everymath{\fam\thettfam}}
  {}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \sbox0{$\mathtt{\xdef\thettfam{\the\fam}}$}%
}

\begin{document}

$x_{i,j} \leq 0$ % normal style
\begin{specialMath}
\begin{supertabular}{r}
$x_{i,j} \leq 0$\\ % typewriter, slightly smaller
\end{supertabular}
\end{specialMath}
$x_{i,j} \leq 0$ % normal style again
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain your code. It's usable, yes, but not reproducible in the sense that for any small modification I would have to come back here.

Comment: @stefan The code does the same as yours, but in an easier way; instead of `\scriptsize`, a `\small` declaration is issued. It wasn't really clear what you need the code for.

Comment: well I didn't understand the code, I simply copied it from another answer here on tex.stackexchange.com. It did what I wanted, but not completely. It's a cryptic hack and I would like to understand a bit more.